# htaccess 301 redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess, constants

Well, I have website with such structure of pages:

domain.com/group-1/page/  and now I need to make htaccess 301 redirect to

domain.com/group-1/**{constant}**-page/

where **{constant}** any fixed word (plus minus sign). This rule should not effect any other groups, except group-1

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `mod_rewrite`. Put this .htaccess code into the domain's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^group-1/page/(.*)$ group-1/constant-page/$1 [L,R=301]
```